# String from HTML attribute to javascript object

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have HTML like this:

```
<div data-test="{ test1: 100, test2: 200, collection: [{ col1: 50, col2: 80 }, { col1: 65, col2: 20 }] }"></div>
```

I want to turn it into a javascript object.

```
var test = SOMETHING( $("div").data("test") );
```

Obviously the string isn't valid JSON so `JSON.Parse` is no use here. I can't render it as valid JSON as that would require double quotes which would mess with my HTML formatting.

I can do it like this:

```
var test = eval("(" + $("div").data("test") + ")");
```

I would rather not use `eval` so I'm looking for an alternative. I haven't come across anything that achieves this for a case like this.

**Edit:**
Marked as duplicate by a guy who is upset I did not accept his sub-standard answer (which he has admitted was sub-standard by deleting it). This question stands on its own and has a resolution. It should be reopened.

Comment: I believe this is what you're trying to do:

    `var realJson = $("#el").data("test").replace((/([\w]+)(:)/g), "\"$1\"$2");`

Outputs:

    `{
        "test1": 100,
        "test2": 200,
        "collection": [
            {
                "col1": 50,
                "col2": 80
            },
            {
                "col1": 65,
                "col2": 20
            }
        ]
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't render it as valid JSON as that would require double quotes which would mess with my HTML formatting.

You can escape the double quotes: `data-test="{ \"test1\":...` or wrap it in single quotes: `data-test='{"test1":...`

Comment: True but messy. Hoping for a nicer solution to be honest.

Comment: This is obviously the most robust solution though you can do it simply by encoding the quotation marks - `&quot;`. Attempts to fudge things with regex and the likes are fragile and although readability it reduced this is, in the long term, not worth the cost.